# Cannot call function within deployed contract

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to get a deployed HelloWorld contract to run within a node app. I want to run the `call()` function to check it like this:

```
const deployed = helloWorldContract.new({
  from: acct1,
  data: compiled.contracts[':HelloWorld'].bytecode,
  gas: 151972,
  gasPrice: 5
}, (error, contract) => {
    if(!error){
      console.log(contract.displayMessage.call());
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Here is the contract for reference:

```
contract HelloWorld {
  function displayMessage() public constant returns (string){
    return "hello from smart contract - {name}";
  }
}
```

When I try `console.log(contract.displayMessage.call())` in the callback, that returns: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`, but, when I log `console.log(contract.displayMessage)` it returns this:

```
{ [Function: bound ]
   request: [Function: bound ],
   call: [Function: bound ],
   sendTransaction: [Function: bound ],
   estimateGas: [Function: bound ],
   getData: [Function: bound ],
   '': [Circular] }
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I run the function `call` within the deployed contract?

Comment: isn't it a function rather than a property?

Comment: Correct. If it was a property wouldn't I access with `contract.displayMessage.call` ? If it's a function do I not access it with `contract.displayMessage.call()` ? Added the contract code to the question for clarity

Comment: I mean displayMessage?

Comment: Yes it is a function, defined in my contract, though `console.log(contract.displayMessage)` will return the object posted above.

If I run `console.log(contract.displayMessage());` on its own I get : `contract.displayMessage is not a function`

If I run `console.log(contract.displayMessage().call());` I get: `contract.displayMessage is not a function`

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue may be caused by the `.new` constructor. I personally don't recommend using it because it is weird. Instead, you should deploy the bytecode as a standard transaction.

Anyways, if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/lib/web3/contract.js#L221-L224) of `.new` you'll see that the callback is actually *called twice*. It is completely non standard and as far as I know, undocumented.

The first time the callback is called after the transaction is sent, and the `contract` object will have `transactionHash` set.

The second time the callback is called, the `contract` object should have the `address` property set. This is what you want, because without the address property, you cannot invoke the contract methods.

In short, try this

```
const deployed = helloWorldContract.new({
  from: acct1,
  data: compiled.contracts[':HelloWorld'].bytecode,
  gas: 151972,
  gasPrice: 5
}, (error, contract) => {
    if (error){
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log(contract);
      if (contract.address) {
        console.log(contract.displayMessage());
      }
    }
});
```

To deploy a contract without using `.new` method, you first need to generate the contract bytecode and ABI. You can get it from using [solc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc) or online solidity compiler or whatever other way.

Then to deploy the contract you use `web3.eth.sendTransaction` with `data` parameter set to the bytecode, and an empty `to` address. `sendTransaction` will return you a `transactionHash`, which you need to wait to be mined and confirmed. The easiest way to do this is through polling - a good starting point can be this method I wrote - https://gist.github.com/gaiazov/17c9fc7fdedf297e82386b74b34c61cd

If your contract takes constructor arguments, they are appended to the bytecode, e.g. `data: bytecode + encodedConstructorArguments`.

Comment: Many thanks for this! You are correct, It was being called twice, I didn't have a clue (as I didn't even get that far).
Could you maybe provide a suggestion as to how I could deploy the bytecode as a standard transaction?

Comment: I added a short description about how to deploy contracts without the "new" method. Its a bit high-level but I hope it helps!